# sharing methods across 2 service layers

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, service-layer

I'm developing an application with MVC3 and Entity Framework. I have service layers for two entities that have one similarity.

The two services are DurationService and FieldService. The former handles a list of Days and daysettings. These settings contain information about the timeslots per day (start time, end time, a list of possible break times). The latter service handles a list of Fields and fieldsettings. These fieldsettings are used to determine the field availability.

Both services need to check whether the break times overlap. I coded this for the DurationService but have now noticed that the FieldService requires exactly the same method. I don't want to violate the DRY principle so my question is, how do I best handle this?

Do I make a static class which both services can call? Do I use some kind of inheritance (even though this method is the only method they will share).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like architecture is preventing you from doing the obviously right things. Don't let that happen.

Inheritance is probably not the right solution. A static helper class will do. Simple problems require simple solutions.